# Wordpress search results page bug after second page

Tags: wordpress, search, url-rewriting

I have a Wordpress site with the internal search option enabled. So when I try to search for a post I can see the first page of results here

http://159.65.220.225/?s=obispo

but when I click on the pagination link and try to pull the next page

http://159.65.220.225/page/2/?s=obispo

It sends a Page Not Found legend and I'm not able to see the next results even though the results are there.

I guess it has something to do with the rewrite since I have another site that is behaving correctly but I can't find where is the issue.

Any suggestions on this? This has already been driving me crazy

Thanks,
Leo

Answer (score 1):

You check your pagination function and also your fetch system should be separate all items by unique ID. like `$post->ID`.